# glReadPixels() doesn't return an Anti-aliased picture

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, antialiasing, msaa

When I render my scene to the screen, the scene uses a `_MultiSampling Anti-Aliasing 8x;` it's ok.

But I want to read to the pixel buffers through `glReadPixels()`, I have a Aliased-Image with Aliased lines. **It doesn't use the 8x MSAA**.

**Code:**

```
glReadPixels(0,0, w, h, GL_BGRA_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void*)pixels);
```

How do I access to the pixels buffer with the MSAA transformation (filter)?

`glReadPixels` doesn't have a special parameter.

**Side Note:** I would like to use the Opengl 1

**Important Note:** I use Qt 5.9's QOpenGLWidget class

Comment: `glReadPixels()` reads what you see on the screen. If it reads non-AA image, then your AA is not working.

Comment: Do `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);` to read from the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that you're rendering to an off-screen renderbuffer or texture via FBO. The solution is to create a renderbuffer that uses a MSAA pixelformat. **Antialiasing is not a postprocessing filter!** (at least not in the form MSAA implements it).